# flatmap after async method?

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java, observable, flatmap

I have a requirement to call xxx method in async manner and return successful response immediatly. However, my xxx() method is not executing anything after flatMap().

```
public Observable<ReturnDataType> performOperations(List PhoneList){
  xxx(PhoneList);
  return Observable.just(return successObservable);
}

private void xxx(List PhoneList){
Observable.from(phoneList).flatMap(phone -> {
 doSomeOperations
}).toList();
}
```

Question:
If any method is called in async manner then does it behaves like this ?
Am I missing anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: You actual code doesn't really make much sense - not sure where this `successObservable` comes from, or the purpose of this use case?? However your `Observable.from(phoneList)` has no subscribers, you need to call `.subscribe()` on the chain.

Comment: successObservable is just another method setting some values in object and returning. I tried using subscribe but still it's not covering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be modified as follows:

```
    Observable.from(phoneList)
            .flatMap(phone -> {
                doSomeOperations;
            })
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .first();
```

One more thing, the code seems more appropriate to use Completable than Observable.

```
    Observable.from(phoneList)
            .flatMap(phone -> {
                doSomeOperations;
            })
            .toCompletable()
            .await();
```